# Openlayer - Unable bind popup on marker

Tags: javascript, openlayers, marker, openstreetmap

I have tried to create popup for marker. But it's displaying some where else in the map as shown in the figure.
Am bit of confused in this scenario.
Please give me solution.

[image]

`JS` code i have tried

```
var newlonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( Lon1, Lat1 )
    .transform( new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
        );
    var zoom=9;
    var newmarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(newmarkers);
    newmarkers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(newlonLat));
    map.setCenter (newlonLat, zoom);


    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup("chicken",
        new OpenLayers.LonLat(Lon1, Lat1),
        new OpenLayers.Size(200,200),
        "example popup",
        true);

    map.addPopup(popup);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are giving wrong coordinations to popup. Did you try to define popup like this?:

```
popup = new OpenLayers.Popup("chicken", 
newlonLat, 
new OpenLayers.Size(200,200), 
"example popup", 
true);
```

Comment: Did it answered your question? If so, please check answer as "answered"